# what is the best js drag and drop framework?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

i need to build diagram builder in js to be cross browser , what do you think will be the best light drag and drop frame work ?

Answer (score 5):

jquery-ui's [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) has worked well for me in the past.